# How can I prove that $\int_{a}^{b} f(x)g(x) dx = g(a)\int_{a}^{c} f(x) dx +g(b)\int_{c}^{b} f(x) dx$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

Let $f$ be a continuous function on $[a, b]$. If $g$ is decreasing monotone and bounded in $[a, b]$ using the mean value theorem, prove that there exists $c \in [a, b]$ such that:

$$\int_{a}^{b} f(x)g(x) dx   = g(a)\int_{a}^{c} f(x) dx +g(b)\int_{c}^{b} f(x) dx$$

I tried to do $h(x) = g(x)-g(a)$ but failed

Comment: Perfect,  I will erase the question

Comment: The problem is that the other post does not using the mean value theorem

Comment: The answer in the other post explicitly mentions the “generalized MVT.”

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, I would define

$$F(c)=g(a)\int_{a}^{c}f(x)dx+g(b)\int_{c}^{b}f(x)dx$$

At $c=a$, we get that

$$F(a)=g(a)\int_{a}^{a}f(x)dx+g(b)\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=g(b)\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$$

likewise at $c=b$ we get that

$$F(b)=g(a)\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx+g(b)\int_{b}^{b}f(x)dx=g(a)\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$$

Since $g(x)$ is decreasing we get that

$$\int_{a}^bf(x)g(x)dx<\int_{a}^b f(x)g(a)dx=F(b)$$

and

$$\int_{a}^bf(x)g(x)dx>\int_{a}^b f(x)g(b)dx=F(a)$$

thus, since $F(c)$ is continuous on [a,b] and

$$F(a)<\int_{a}^bf(x)g(x)dx<F(b)$$

we can use the intermediate value theorem to confirm that there is a value $c$ on (a,b) such that

$$F(c)=\int_{a}^bf(x)g(x)dx$$

which is the solution.

Comment: The estimate $\int_{a}^bf(x)g(x)dx<\int_{a}^b f(x)g(a)dx$ would require that $f$ is non-negative.